# How to access a database in Django but without ORM support

Tags: python, django, database-connection, mysql-error-1064, mysql-python

I have a second database in my Django application, which is filled with static data about the equivalent of zipcodes in my country (Brazil) and the related streets, neighborhoods, cities and states.

I'm trying to access it like this:

```
from django.db import connections
from django.conf import settings

try:
    cursor = connections[settings.CEP_DATABASE_NAME].cursor()
    ....
```

but I get the following Error:

```
OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'cep'")
```

My settings.py:

```
CEP_DATABASE_NAME = 'cep'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'hypersaber',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST' : 'localhost',
        'PORT' : '3306',
        'OPTIONS' : {"init_command": "SET storage_engine=INNODB"}
    },
    CEP_DATABASE_NAME: {
        'NAME': CEP_DATABASE_NAME,
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST' : 'localhost',
        'PORT' : '3306',
        'OPTIONS' : {"init_command": "SET storage_engine=INNODB"}
    }
}
```

Both my MySQL DB instances are up and running.

Am I missing some configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me.

I have to ask the obvious: Does that database actually exist on localhost?

That's an exception thrown from the MySQLdb module, which makes me think there's nothing django-specific going wrong here and is why I ask if it's just a real, low-level error.

Can you access the database from a regular (non django) python script?

Comment: As I said, "Both my MySQL DB instances are up and running.". So: yes, it does. I was afraid that some more configuration was required. Is my code "enough"?

Comment: I can access it using a workbench-like program (HeidiSQL) without any problem.

Comment: Pretty strange then - can you post the full stack trace?  Is it the cursor() call that causes is?  I'm also working on a django project with multiple databases and I just did a little test to see that I could access the secondary database via django.db.connections.

Comment: You say both your mySQL DB instances..  are you running two MySQLs on different hosts/ports?  It looks like you are accessing localhost:3306 for both dbs.  Sorry to keep digging in this direction, but once you have eliminated the impossible ..

Comment: Thanks for your attention and patience. It turned out to be a  silly mistake, as you first predicted. I populated this database from a dump, and the database name was not 'cep', but 'hypersaber_cep', hence the reason I was not able to access it. I'm sorry for wasting your time, but at least I leard that all my configuration code was OK!

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to prod you in the right direction.  Sometimes it just helps talking through the problem.